# Spring scheduled task status at @PreDestroy hook

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a Spring app I have a Service with a relatively high-frequency (scheduled every 100ms) tasks. Every task in turn spawns a subscription from an elastic reactor scheduler so I manually control the concurrency - ScheduledPoolExecutor is only responsible for scheduling the task every 100ms, after that tasks are running in a completely detached mode.

In order to do a graceful shutdown, I need to clean these up in a @PreDestroy hook.

My question is: is scheduler stopped by the time control reaches a Bean's @PreDestroy hook (i.e can I safely assume that no more tasks would be scheduled during the @PreDestroy hook)?

Comment: I guess you mean `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`? If yes then you can use the `shutdown()` method. Or the `awaitTermination()` which allows you to set a timeout

Comment: So you're saying that `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` isn't already shutdown by the time control reaches `@PreDestroy` (that is, I have to manually shut it down). The thing is, there are mutliple services in the app using the same executor for different tasks...

Comment: Another way would be to save all the scheduled tasks in a `Collection` then in the `PreDestroy` `cancel()` all the tasks